# Gauge central value don't show

Tags: highcharts

I only want to know if it's possible delete, or don't show, the frame in the middle of Gauge Chart that contains the value (below pivot). I got more than one serie and values ​​overlap each other.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

One way is, you can format your **`datalabels`** and return nothing in the **`formatter ()`** function.

```
 dataLabels: {
     formatter: function () {
     var kmh = this.y,
     mph = Math.round(kmh * 0.621);                
     }
 }
```

[**`Fiddled version`**](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/v9Dtw/). (tweaked from Highchart [demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-dual) sample )

Hope this is you need.

Comment: Great!! It's just what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is

```
dataLabels: false
```

Documentaion: [Gauge DataLabels enabled](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.gauge.dataLabels.enabled)